# How to have calendar events indexed by search engines

Tags: seo, search-engine

I'm developing a site for which one of the main components is an events calendar.  For users, the calendar is offered in 3 formats

1. an interactive AJAX web calendar (monthly view)
2. an iCal subscription feed
3. a downloadable PDF

None of these seem particularly search-engine friendly.  What would be the best way to make sure the individual events are being indexed?

My ideal situation is where, for example, a user would type into a search engine "[company name] craft fair" and land on the calendar page for November 2010 which is showing the fall craft fair event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`<noscript>`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_noscript.asp) tag to provide this information to search engines and users that have disabled javascript in a textual format.

Comment: Part of me was hoping for a really easy solution, but this is probably my best approach.  I basically re-implemented a simple version of the web calendar using [noscript], and setup my sitemap to index back and forward 1 month.

Answer (score 0):

All events should be exposed as individual, seo optimized links and included in sitemap.

Request to this link should open specified item or whole calendar with selected item.

Comment: This was my initial idea, but it felt weird having a page be a search engine result when that page would never otherwise be found by the user.  I did incorporate end up incorporating the sitemap though as you mentioned.